# Woocommerce Subscription Cancel Button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a function that adds a "Cancel" button to my Subscriptions Listings with woocommerce subscriptions.

The problem is that when I click I get the error:

> Security error. Please contact us if you need assistance.

My current code is:

```
add_action('woocommerce_my_subscriptions_actions', 'cancelButton', 15);
function cancelButton( $subscription ) {
    $status = $subscription->get_status();
    $sub_id = $subscription->get_order_number();
    $cancel_url = wp_nonce_url( '?subscription_id=' . $sub_id . '&change_subscription_to=cancelled' );
    if ( $status == 'active' || $status == 'on-hold' || $status == 'pending' ) {
        echo '<a href="' . $cancel_url . '" class="button view" onclick="alert("Tem certeza que deseja cancelar sua assinatura?")">' .  __( 'Cancelar', 'starling' ) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

I have also tried another method, but it doesn't work when there is a date on the following bill date. The diference is only inside the "echo".

```
echo '<a href="' . $subscription->get_cancel_order_url() . '" class="button view" onclick="alert("Tem certeza que deseja cancelar sua assinatura?")">' .  __( 'Cancelar', 'starling' ) . '</a>';
```

I couldn't find the correct method to call this button, so I have tried creating my own.

I am still learning to code, so there might be room for a lot of improvements. The "onclick" alert is also not working.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

I have finally worked on a solution.

Looks like I was missing a few arguments when using "wp_nonce_url", woocommerce subscriptions requires the the ID and current status of the subscription inside the action to verify the request before processing it.

I managed to understand this logic by going through the core of Woocommerce Subscriptions and looking at how they created their links and how they process them. I haven't found any documentations about it.

```
wp_nonce_url( $url, $subscription_id . $current_status );
```

So my code now looks like this...

```
add_action('woocommerce_my_subscriptions_actions', 'cancelButton', 15);
function cancelButton( $subscription ) {
    $current_status = $subscription->get_status();
    $subscription_id = $subscription->get_order_number();
    $subscription_url = $subscription->get_view_order_url();
    $cancel_url = $subscription_url . '?subscription_id=' . $subscription_id . '&change_subscription_to=cancelled';
    $cancel_subscription_url = wp_nonce_url( $cancel_url, $subscription_id . $current_status );

    if ( $current_status == 'active' || $current_status == 'on-hold' || $current_status == 'pending' ) {
        echo '<a href="' . $cancel_subscription_url . '" class="button view" onclick="alert("Tem certeza que deseja cancelar sua assinatura?")">' .  __( 'Cancelar', 'starling' ) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else too!

Comment: How did you get the $subscription object?